# Continuation not running C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Consider the following code

```
class Program
{

    static void Continue()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Continue t1"); 
    }

    static async Task AsyncStart()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("AsyncStart"); 
        return;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task t3 = AsyncStart().ContinueWith((ant) => { Continue(); });

        Console.Out.WriteLine("BEFORE"); 
        Task.WhenAny(new Task[] { t3 });
        Console.Out.WriteLine("AFTER");
     }
 }
```

The output is

```
AsyncStart
BEFORE
AFTER
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Continuation is not running!!!!

Yes, I understand the AsyncStart does not contain any await (CS1998), but I still expect t3 to run the continuation.  I am missing something very basic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your process ended before the continuation (which runs on a background thread) had the chance to run.

Comment: Matt is right. For demo just append `Console.ReadKey(true);` to the `main`.

Comment: Wow It was really basic I thought all tasks are executing in one thread similar to yield .

Comment: Is there any way to ensure the continuation is running in the same thread?

Comment: @Boris, that's a different question that shouldn't be discussed in the comments.  Search and you'll find plenty on that topic.

Comment: Thanks, God bless you and stack overflow community :)

Answer (score 1):

`Task.WhenAny` returns a `Task` which you either need to `await` in which case you'll need to do in in an `async` method (Main can't be marked as `async`). Alternatively because you are in a console app you can call `Task.WaitAll` and that should wait for the continuation to complete. In a GUI app WaitAll can cause a deadlock, but in a console app it is ok.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

   Task t3 = AsyncStart().ContinueWith((ant) => { Continue(); });

   Console.Out.WriteLine("BEFORE"); 
   Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t3 });
   Console.Out.WriteLine("AFTER");
}
```